# Handle Paginated api on the client side

Tags: objective-c, swift, rest, pagination, api-design

I've created an api which following three parameters `page`, `longitude`, `latitude`. So when doing a request you pass the users location and a given page and the api will return a page of organizations sorted by the users location. This data is saved/updated on the client side in a mobile database. My question is when trying to populate this data in a view, how do i on the client side know which data is updated and which is not since it is a paginated api it will only update/save the number of objects that is on a page?

So far i've tried just to populate the number of objects that it retrieved on a page, however objects in the api might switch page depending on how quickly the user changes position? i've thought about making some kind of flag in my mobile database objects when requesting data, but not quite sure what to do in this case?

Comment: I've accomplished to retrieve the data, but i need guidance on designing this from a client perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inclined to think that your local database is relevant for the current location of the user, defined by it's longitude and latitude. So I would suggest that you clean up the local database if the user changes his position, and repopulate with what you get from the server for the new position.

That would be the simplistic approach. If, as you mention, for a nearby location you get organizations that appeared in a different page in the previous location, a possible optimisation is to store in the DB the current page (and position within the page) of each organization. When you retrieve the new location, you check if each organization received is already stored in the DB (organizations would need to have a unique id to do this), and then alter the position/page to match what is received from the server for the new location.

Comment: Okay but isnt it bad practice to clear local database, in terms of cache?

Comment: Not at all, it just depends on the case, and the reason you have a local cache in the first place... For offline usage? For performance?... In your situation, if the user changes position too often maybe it doesn't make sense. It also depends on how big the cache is at a given time and many other factors... But anyway, as I mentioned in my answer, if you can identify the organizations received, you can opt for a more optimized solution.